# C# Texture2D SetData ARGB?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to make a Texture2D from a Bitmap. I have

```
Texture2D BitmapToTexture(Bitmap img)
{
    var ret = new Texture2D(Game.GraphicsDevice, img.Width, img.Height);
    var bd = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    int[] bytes = new int[img.Width * img.Height];
    Marshal.Copy(bd.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    ret.SetData(bytes);
    img.UnlockBits(bd);
    return ret;
}
```

The issue is that SetData is for some reason expecting ABGR. Is there a way to get SetData
 to take ARGB data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You have to swap the bytes yourself.

The byte ordering was [changed in XNA 4.0 (see last paragraph)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx).

See also [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/bitmap-to-texture2d-problem-with-colors/6442#6442).